# Input field scrollbar too small with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter Bootstrap with play! framework to develop a little web app.

I don't know too much about css, and here comes my problem:

I have two divs, one near the other, and one of these has a text field  (I have a little form

inside),but when I click on the text fild the old entries appear, and I like this, but they

don't go under the bottom of the div, I have only a little scrollbar with only one element

and an half. I get that the problem is that I try to go under the div, but I can get how to

solve it.

Comment: Do you have any code for us to look at?

Comment: Any code or URL to look at ?